# find sortest path in mutablearray in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ipad, google-maps

I have ten Location with origin. i want shortest path `NSMutableArray`.

For example

These are my locations:

```
Starting point(Current Location):-  Ahmedabad 0 km    (lat:XXXXXXX,lng:XXXXXXX)
                  Gandhinagar 30 km (lat:XXXXXXX,lng:XXXXXXX)
                  Rajkot 200 km     (lat:XXXXXXX,lng:XXXXXXX)
                  Limdi  100 km     (lat:XXXXXXX,lng:XXXXXXX)
                  Junagadh 300 km   (lat:XXXXXXX,lng:XXXXXXX)
                  Vanthli 315 km    (lat:XXXXXXX,lng:XXXXXXX)
                  palanpur 400 km   (lat:XXXXXXX,lng:XXXXXXX)
                  keshod 350 km     (lat:XXXXXXX,lng:XXXXXXX)
                  veraval 420 km    (lat:XXXXXXX,lng:XXXXXXX)
```

i want shortest array like this

```
 Output:- Ahmedabad
          Gandhinagar
          Limdi
          Rajkot
          Junagadh
          Vanthli
          Keshod
          Veraval
          Palanpur
```

Means in first position is my starting point so `Ahmedabad is First`, Gandhinagar is nearest from ahmedabad so `Gandhinagar is second`, then limdi is nearest than gandhinagar so `Limdi is third`, rajkot is nearest from Limdi so `Rajkot is Forth`, at last i have to cover all the locations with shortest algorithm,

i use `Google's Distance Matrix` API but it time consuming. (because i have to call this method 8 times than i get exact result.)

Is there any method or algorithm to find out and return me shortest `NSMutableArray`

Comment: What exactly is the structure of your Array ?

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can do is simply make an `NSDictionary` instead of an `NSMutableArray` and use `objectForKey` for the names of the cities and using these compare the distances . Hope this will work.

Comment: in short i want to draw shortest path on map which cover all the points(Locations).

Comment: Have you used an nsdictionary before >?

Comment: yes i used the NSDictionary. but my exact question is that i want to find shortest path from the multiple locations. if it is in NSArray or  in NSDictionary is doesn't matter.

Comment: Cant u compare the distances in the objects ?